# magento 1.9.1.0 local.xml is not working

Tags: php, html, css, xml, magento

I am new to magento and I'm trying to create custom themes. I have created a local.xml on the app/design/frontend/customize/main/layout. The problem that I'm facing right now is that the local.xml is not working. My goal is to remove some logo and to include css and js file. I also declare on the system what theme and skin is to be used. This is my code..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"></remove>
        <remove name="bml.center.logo"></remove>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/jquery.bxslider.min.js</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

How can I make the local.xml working?

Thanks

EDIT:::

The system ignores the local.xml file

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: The system can't recognized or just ignore local.xml

Answer (score 1):

The `<remove>` tags should be inside `<reference name="block_name">` tags as well. Also use `<action method="addItem">` to add a skin js file.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly determine if your layout working at all. Put there something like `<remove name="header" />`

Then you have a bug in `<action method="addJs">` Add JS is function inside some class Block. If you search it you can find following:

```
public function addJs($name, $params = "")
{
    $this->addItem('js', $name, $params);
    return $this;
}
```

It means that function in your case expect to get only javascript file name.

```
        <action method="addJs">
            <name>js/jquery.bxslider.min.js</name>
        </action>
```

In this method you also can see that this function calls method `addItem`. It means that you can use

```
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/jquery.bxslider.min.js</name>
        </action>
```

As you use jQuery library - you need to add noConflict() function to let jQuery and native library of magento - prototype work together.

Create new script or just add to head following:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Dont forget that if you include javascript code in header - you need to wrap it into `<script></script>`

Then you need to be sure, that path to script is correct. Look at your page source code and find where you attached scripts and check if they are available at this way.

And the last advice. Replace you handle `<default>` with some specific handle (for example based on module_controller_action)